# Django rest framework list by BrowsableAPI and create with custom button

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm kinda newbie to DRF and need some advice pls.

I created some kind of time duration record for each day which is ok with inputing the duration manually, here is **a model:**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, date

class Record(models.Model):
    recordDate = models.DateField(blank=True, default=date.today)
    hourAchieved = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["recordDate"]
    def __str__(self):
        return "Achieved "+str(self.hourAchieved)+" hour(s)!"
```

and works well with these **APIviews:**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Record
from .serializers import (
    recordListSerializer,
    recordUpdateSerializer
)

class recordList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = recordListSerializer

class recordUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = recordUpdateSerializer
```

Then, I want to **improve input process** by create a button to get 'start_time' and another button to get 'end_time' and calculate the time for me instead of me remember and input duration time(hours) myself.

So, I found the **'TemplateHTMLRender'** and decided to use it as:

```
class recordList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = recordListSerializer
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
    template_name = 'myTemp.html'

    def get(self, request):
        records = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = recordListSerializer(records,many=True,context={'request': request})
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'record':records})
```

and this is **myTemp.html:**

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<html>
<body>
<h1>Neew Era of REST</h1>
<form action="{% url 'record:list' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here comes the problem, it told me

> 'ListSerializer' object is not iterable

I've no idea.....

**Edit: Serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Record
from datetime import date
from django.urls import reverse

class recordListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Add = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        read_only=True,
        view_name='record:detail'
        )
    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            todayRecord = Record.objects.get(recordDate=date.today())
        except Record.DoesNotExist:
            todayRecord = None
        if todayRecord is not None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You recorded for today!")
        return data
```

PS. I thought it because I only have 1 record, and added it , and it doesn't help

Comment: Stack trace? Which part of code is causing the error?

Comment: How about your serialozer definition

Comment: @KevinL. When I go to 'recordList' view, and it told me that:
'ListSerializer' object is not iterable

PS. I already added serializer, hope it help.